# Can you re-name the Up-sell feature?

Tags: up-sells

is it possible to rename "upsell Products"? for example change it to "you might also like.."

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For front-end  you will find the text on given file location: go to exact path to your current running theme.

`app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml`